# How to sentence tokenize within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

One of the columns in my dataframe has text such as:

```
'This is very good. No it is very bad. Actually it is alright'
```

I'd like to sentence tokenize of the texts in this column essentially creating a nested list of sentences.

I have tried

```
def tokenizeAndList(text):

    raw_text = text
    nlp = English()
    nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer')) # updated
    doc = nlp(raw_text)
    sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
    return(sentences)

out=myText['findings'].map(tokenizeAndList)
```

this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NAType' has no len()
```

How can I create my nested list?

Comment: From which package `English()` instance come from?

Comment: Please show `SpaCy` version and [reprex] of your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have some values that are not of string type in the `findings` column.

You should check if the `text` is of type `str` before creating a Spacy doc out of it, else return the value as is:

```py
nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'))

def tokenizeAndList(text):
    if isinstance(text, str):
        doc = nlp(text)
        return [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
    else:
        return text
```